# Chofetz Chaim's Advice to Son

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, chofetz-chaim, torah-writing

A Rav mentioned that Chofetz Chaim told his son (a Rav) to appoint leaders of the community to take care of the chesed needs in order to address more global issues - noting that he himself writes seforim to reach a grander scale.

Where does the Chofetz Chaim say this?

Comment: Probably if it exists it would be recorded in his son's biography of his dad. I'm just guessing. Book with a very long title I always forget it

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you mean the son’s intro. to “Nidhe Yisrael/The Dispersed of Israel” (pub. 1951)?

Comment: @olive the one I'm thinking of is something like דרכיו מנהגיו פסקיו ותורתו של החפץ חיים maybe there are others

Comment: @DoubleAA Title length checks out

Comment: @Oliver see title of book in answer

Answer (score 4):

This may be a reference to what his son writes in the first section of שיחות החפץ חיים דרכיו נמוקיו ושיחותיו מחיי אבא  in #27:

> לא ישר היה בעיניו דרכי בימי נעורי ששקעתי בעניני חסד ובעניני צבור לכונן ולתקן דברים הרבה ובשביל זה בטלתי מלמודי הרבה זמנים באמרו לי כי לתקן ולספק צרכי עדה הקטנה ביותר אף של חמישים משפחות לא יספיק זמן של כל החיים והאם זוהי דרך הישרה הלא ידעת כי גם אנכי לא רחוק ממדת החסד והטבה אבל לא אבלה כל זמני על זה רק אנכי מחבר ספרים על מדות האלה ומפיצם בין אלפי ישראל ולומדים בהם ובאים לידי מעשה
>
> It was not proper in his eyes my approach in my youth where I immersed myself in matters of kindness and matters of the community, to arrange and fix many things, and on account of this I lost from my learning many times. He would say to me that to fix and to satisfy all the needs of the smallest community, even of [only] 50 families, an entire lifetime would be insufficient. And is this the proper way? Do you not know that I  too am not distant from the trait of kindness and goodness, but I do not squander all my time on this. Rather, I write books about these traits and spread them among the thousands of Israel, and they learn them and come to actualization.